# why strings are terminated with null character in java?

Tags: java

Today I have read that strings are terminated with null character in java. But why is it necessary since length of the string is already maintained by the length variable of the sting class ? So it's kind of strange thing to me. Please someone clarify it to me.

Thanks

Comment: Strings are *not* terminated with a null character in Java.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java strings are not null terminated. They end with the length in `length`. You can make a `\0` the last character of a Java string, but that doesn't automatically terminate the string. The length of `12<\0>45` would still be 5 and not 2 as in C.

Answer (score 7):

Don't believe everything you read.  In the screen shot below, you can see there is no null-termination.[image]

Comment: Yes, most debugger can show that.  A "string" in C is just a contiguous set bytes of memory, so a string of "123" should show '1','2','3','\0'.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation mentions nothing of the sort. I'd assume that you read wrong.

If some Java implementation null-terminates strings, then it is an implementation detail, but nothing that is guaranteed by the language specification. (And, of course, as assylias notes, Strings may contain U+0000 in Java.) This isn't unheard of, though. VB's strings pointed to the beginning and were null-terminated, making them compatible with normal C APIs and their length was stored before the beginning of the string.

Comment: here is the link .. 

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/33348-string-tutorial/

Comment: @Joey that implementation seems unlikely since `\u000` is a valid character.

Comment: @AmitBhaira Find a different (if possible better) tutorial, for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Comment: @AmitBhaira And if you want to read the actual documentation, go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28%29). Notice the difference between the official constructor definition and the one in your tutorial.

Answer (score -4):

This tactic of having both a length field and keeping the string null terminated is often employe because many libraries and api's expects null terminated strings.

This means that you still get the performance increase of keeping the length seperate and the ability to directly pass your strings to api's wihtout having to create a copy of the string. In short: the best of two worlds at only a bytes expense.

Comment: This is simply wrong for Java.