# How String terminate in java is it terminate by '\0' like C++?

Tags: java, android

**How String terminate in java is it terminate by '\0' like C++?**

If we have String = "I am string".
So How java know string is now going to end like C++ string terminate by '\0' char

Comment: Does it matter? C-Strings are basically byte arrays, or pointers to such, so there needs to be some indication of how many bytes are in it. In Java, this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As explained well here - [why-strings-are-terminated-with-null-character-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595209/why-strings-are-terminated-with-null-character-in-java),

They end with the length in length. You can make a `\0` the last character of a Java string, but that doesn't automatically terminate the string. The length of `12<\0>45` would still be `5` and not `2` as in `C`.